# How to stop key event propagation in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Template:

```
<template>
    <input keydown.delegate='onKeydown($event)' keyup.delegate='onKeyup($event)'/>
</template>
```

The View model:

```
export class MyInput {
    onKeydown(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // return false; // this does't matter as it only prevents default
    }
    onKeyup(e) {
        console.log(e); // will still fire even [stopPropagation] was called
    }

}
```

The expected behavior of this would be: `onKeyup` doesn't fire but I'm getting this no matter what.

How do I stop key event propagation in Aurelia ?

Comment: Based on Ashley Grant answer: This is expected behavior. `stopPropagation` will indeed stop it from propagating upper level.

To stop `keyup` to happen on the same element, use `stopImmediatePropagation`

[MDN: Event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is expected. See this gist: https://gist.run/?id=3b98d602713a9a80a28834f61db6a73f where I use the standard `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` HTML attributes to attach event handlers to bog standard JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

works instead of

```
e.stopPropagation()
```